# Metrics to check and compare the development experience (for developers) of SharePoint installation on local servers versus Azure

Tags: installation, azure

We are trying to compare the development experience (for developers)  on local (in-house) servers and on Windows Azure hosting. We need to identify whether having a setup locally on our servers is better than using Windows Azure for SharePoint installation.

**Purpose is to find out which approach is better for developers to work interms of speed, connectivity, and any other issues.**

Can you suggest some metrics to evaluate this?

Comment: For me: Recycle time (time from recycle or IISRESET until we actually get a SharePoint page)

Comment: Do you mean the time required for the 1st request after an IISRESET (for example after a farm wsp deployment)?

Comment: Robert's suggestion is a good one. You could run iisreset any time and just refresh/open the page to your SharePoint site. Then record the loading times.

Comment: Exactly, like @moe says. That is the biggest culprit with developing for SP 2013 for me personally. Also, the perceived experience with debugging a solution (since it tends to time-out...) would be nice. No idea how to quantify that to a metric though.

Comment: I will convert this question to a Wiki, since that format is more suitable for this kind of open-ended, some what opinion-based, questions :)

Answer (score 2):

For me:

Recycle time (time from recycle or IISRESET until we actually get a SharePoint page). That is the biggest culprit with developing for SP 2013 for me personally.

Also, the perceived experience with debugging a solution (since it tends to time-out...) would be nice. No idea how to quantify that to a metric though.